# Long distance corney keg transport

Tags: keg, transport

So question: I have movers taking my stuff 1200+ miles, about a week of travel. I have two corneys with finished beer in them. One is almost done and I'll empty in time. The other is 99% full.

I hear transport trucks get very hot. If I let the beer come to room temp and purge to keep the pressure low, I should hopefully be ok right? I'd hate to have to throw a party and to finish a whole batch.

Anyone have insight or previous experience? Of note, yes I now moving companies don't want to transport liquor and high pressure potentially explosive cargo. I did speak with them about the keg and they were fine with it if I purged to keep pressure low.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry about catastrophic beer kerplosion. Should be fine as long as you make sure they're not under high pressure when you load them as a keg is basically a big can of beer.

However my 2c is that sitting in a 100F+ truck for a week isn't going to do any favors for your beer and it's just another damn heavy thing to move. I'd go with your party idea, but I think you should be safe.